# ggplot2 3 side by side histogram plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and have managed to create the following dataframe

```
MinVariance MaxSharpe RiskParity

HYLD       0.44      0.00       0.28

IBTL        0.00      0.07       0.11

IBTM        0.36      0.00       0.15

SGLN        0.00      0.56       0.12

SLXX        0.20      0.00       0.20

VMVL        0.00      0.36       0.14
```

I'd like to create 3 histograms in one plot (side by side) showing the weightings of each assets allocation

Comment: You will have to reflow your data into long format (see i.e. `tidyr::pivot_longer`) and you can use `geom_col` to map x and y to your newly created variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot histogram you can use

```
library(tidyverse)

dfr %>% as_tibble(rownames = 'type') %>%  
  pivot_longer(., cols = -type, names_to = 'vars', values_to = 'vals') %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(vals, fill = type)) + facet_wrap(vars~.)
```

[image]

## Update

```
dfr %>% as_tibble(rownames = 'type') %>%  
  pivot_longer(., cols = -type, names_to = 'vars', values_to = 'vals') %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(y = vals, x = type)) + facet_wrap(vars~.)
```

[image]

## Data

```
dfr = structure(list(MinVariance = c(0.44, 0, 0.36, 0, 0.2, 0), MaxSharpe = c(0, 
0.07, 0, 0.56, 0, 0.36), RiskParity = c(0.28, 0.11, 0.15, 0.12, 
0.2, 0.14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("HYLD", "IBTL", 
"IBTM", "SGLN", "SLXX", "VMVL"))
```

Comment: Hi Bappa yes this is very much what I was looking for, but would like vals on the y axis with type being the x axis repeated for each asset allocation strategy being each histogram.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to have a dodge barplot (you don't want a histogram with discrete variables) :

```r
dfr <- read.table(text = 'MinVariance MaxSharpe RiskParity

HYLD 0.44 0.00 0.28

IBTL 0.00 0.07 0.11

IBTM 0.36 0.00 0.15

SGLN 0.00 0.56 0.12

SLXX 0.20 0.00 0.20

VMVL 0.00 0.36 0.14')

suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(dplyr) )
suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(tidyr) )
suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(ggplot2) )

dfr_long <- dfr %>% as_tibble(rownames = 'type') %>%  
    pivot_longer(., cols = -type, names_to = 'vars', values_to = 'vals')
dfr_long
#> # A tibble: 18 x 3
#>    type  vars         vals
#>    <chr> <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1 HYLD  MinVariance  0.44
#>  2 HYLD  MaxSharpe    0   
#>  3 HYLD  RiskParity   0.28
#>  4 IBTL  MinVariance  0   
#>  5 IBTL  MaxSharpe    0.07
#>  6 IBTL  RiskParity   0.11
#>  7 IBTM  MinVariance  0.36
#>  8 IBTM  MaxSharpe    0   
#>  9 IBTM  RiskParity   0.15
#> 10 SGLN  MinVariance  0   
#> 11 SGLN  MaxSharpe    0.56
#> 12 SGLN  RiskParity   0.12
#> 13 SLXX  MinVariance  0.2 
#> 14 SLXX  MaxSharpe    0   
#> 15 SLXX  RiskParity   0.2 
#> 16 VMVL  MinVariance  0   
#> 17 VMVL  MaxSharpe    0.36
#> 18 VMVL  RiskParity   0.14

dfr_long %>%    
    ggplot( aes(x = vars, y = vals, fill = type) ) +
    geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

Comment: This is not histogram rather it's a barplot.

Comment: This is quite an interesting presentation of data and one I will attempt to seperate for each allocation strategy for clarity thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Try package `ggplot2`  with `geom_histogram` and `facet_wrap`.

Comment: Thanks Erich appreciated